# Geometric intuition of Multivariable Mean Value Theorem for Function of Two Variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, mean-value-theorem

I have prepared a geometric intuition of Multivariable Mean Value Theorem for function of two variables in my own understanding after reading several books. But I am not sure whether is it correct or not. also, i am not able to find any geometrical interpretation on multidimensions so far.

I am providing a link to this topic. Please, if anyone finds the time to go through this, please help.

I am Providing this PDF because there are hand drawn figures which are not available on the internet directly and it does not require any formula, I have only explained what that figure is.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpM249z_XK1ytzdElzNYNQamG_jY4r-O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions posted here are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: yeah true, but it contains figures that are hand drawn and many figures are there. The explanation is only based on figures.

Comment: What precisely is your statement of the result?

Comment: Sir Theodre Shriffin? Really! Thank you sir I am studying proofs from your book also. thank you so much. My precise statement of the geometrical interpretation of MVT was that it gives the slope of tangent line in any direction at given point in the domain of f or we can say directional derivative of f at that point in any given vector direction.. I have tried to draw all the figures on my imagination so they might not be accurate but I  had to give it a try.